# How to easily see what a Azure Synapse changeset contains

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse

Azure Synapse saves all our sql scripts as Json - which is fine - but when I want to look at a changeset for a code review for instance, in azure devops it's very hard to see where all the changes are, because it all ends up in one long row (see picture in link).

Are there any easy fixes for this? Or do I need to copy the *before and after* into some text editor to find what lines all the changes are on?

[Azure Devops/Synapse changeset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvg8K.png)

Comment: Hi there. Have you got a chance to check the answer below? According to the extension description, it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for DevOps which may help. Install the [Synapse artifact native view](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SynapseCodeArtifactNativeView.synapse-artifact-native-view) extension. It only helps in the pull request screen and it reformats a limited list of artifact types like SQL scripts. Hopefully it will help your scenario.

[image: synapse diff tab on pull request screen once extension is installed]